# Bootstrap v4.1.3 Navbar (Hamburger) not working in Mobile View as well as dropdowns

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, nav

I'm migrating one bootstrap HTML website to react, I'm facing an issue in navbar & dropdowns as navbar is not working in mobile view & getting the following Error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')
> at functions.js:52:6
> at functions.js:348:3

> animated_canvas_min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')
> at draw (animated_canvas_min.js:4:220)
> at animate (animated_canvas_min.js:3:46)
> at animated_canvas_min.js:5:8

Followings are the code for my Header & function.js file showing an error

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Header() {

  return (
    <>
    <header class="header menu_fixed">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html" title="BMBC">
                <img src="img/BMBC-1.png" width="165" height="35" alt="" class="logo_normal" />
                <img src="img/BMBC-1.png" width="165" height="35" alt="" class="logo_sticky" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <a id="#menu" class="btn_mobile">
            <div class="hamburger hamburger--spin" id="hamburger">
                <div class="hamburger-box">
                    <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <nav id="menu" class="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><span> <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 input-group-sm">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 " type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 btn-sm btn_red" type="submit">Search</button>
                  </form></span></li>
                <li><span><a href="index.html">Home</a></span></li>
                <li><span><a href="about.html">Why BMBC</a></span></li>
                <li><span><a href="account.html">My Account</a></span></li>
                <li><span><a href="contacts.html">Contact Us</a></span></li>            
                <li><span><a href="#sign-in-dialog" id="sign-in" class="icon-user" title="Sign In">Sign In</a></span></li>      
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
(function ($) {

    "use strict";

    // Sticky nav
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
            $('.header').addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $('.header').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });
    
    // Sticky sidebar
    $('#sidebar').theiaStickySidebar({
        updateSidebarHeight: true,
        additionalMarginTop: 150
    });
    
    // Faq section
    $('#faq_cat').theiaStickySidebar({
        additionalMarginTop: 100
    });
    
    // Mobile Mmenu
    var $menu = $("nav#menu").mmenu({
        "extensions": ["pagedim-black", "theme-dark"],
        counters: true,
        keyboardNavigation: {
            enable: true,
            enhance: true
        },
        navbar: {
            title: 'MENU'
        },
        navbars: [{position:'bottom',content: ['<a href="#0">© 2019 Sparker</a>']}]}, 
        {
        // configuration
        clone: true,
        classNames: {
            fixedElements: {
                fixed: "menu_fixed",
                sticky: "sticky"
            }
        }
    });
    var $icon = $("#hamburger");
    var API = $menu.data("mmenu");
    $icon.on("click", function () {
        API.open();
    });
    API.bind("open:finish", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $icon.addClass("is-active");
        }, 100);
    });
    API.bind("close:finish", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $icon.removeClass("is-active");
        }, 100);
    });
    
    // Rotate icons
    $(".main_categories a").hover(
        function(){$(this).find("i").toggleClass("rotate-x");}
    );
    
    // Modal Sign In
    $('#sign-in').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        fixedContentPos: true,
        fixedBgPos: true,
        overflowY: 'auto',
        closeBtnInside: true,
        preloader: false,
        midClick: true,
        removalDelay: 300,
        closeMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-close"></button>',
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
    });
    
    // Show Password
    $('#password, #password_in').hidePassword('focus', {
        toggle: {
            className: 'my-toggle'
        }
    });

    // Forgot Password
    $("#forgot").click(function () {
        $("#forgot_pw").fadeToggle("fast");
    });
    
    //Scroll to top
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        'use strict';
        if ($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $('#toTop').on('click', function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
    });
    
    /* Animation on scroll */
    new WOW().init();
    
    // Account switch client type
    $('input[name="client_type"]').click(function () {
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
        $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
        $(targetBox).show();
    });
    
    //  Video popups
    $('.video').magnificPopup({type:'iframe'}); /* video modal*/
    
    // Image popups
    $('.magnific-gallery').each(function () {
        $(this).magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a',
            type: 'image',
            preloader: true,
            gallery: {
                enabled: true
            },
            removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
            callbacks: {
                beforeOpen: function () {
                    // just a hack that adds mfp-anim class to markup 
                    this.st.image.markup = this.st.image.markup.replace('mfp-figure', 'mfp-figure mfp-with-anim');
                    this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
                }
            },
            closeOnContentClick: true,
            midClick: true // allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source.
        });
    });
    
    // Other address
    $('#other_addr input').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#other_addr_c').fadeIn('fast');
        else
            $('#other_addr_c').fadeOut('fast');
    });
    
    // Accordion
    function toggleChevron(e) {
        $(e.target)
            .prev('.card-header')
            .find("i.indicator")
            .toggleClass('ti-minus ti-plus');
    }
    $('.accordion_2').on('hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
        function toggleIcon(e) {
        $(e.target)
            .prev('.panel-heading')
            .find(".indicator")
            .toggleClass('ti-minus ti-plus');
    }
    
    // Jquery select
    $('.custom-search-input-2 select, .custom-select-form select').niceSelect();
    
    // Like Icon
    $('.wish_bt').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('liked');
    });
    
    // Search Mobile aside
    $('a.side_panel').on("click", function () {
        $('#search_mobile').toggleClass('show');
        $('.layer').toggleClass('layer-is-visible');
    });
    
    // Search Mobile horizontal
    $('a.search_mob').click(function () {
        $('.search_mob_wp').slideToggle("fast");
    });
    
    // Collapse filters
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if ($(this).width() < 991) {
            $('.collapse#collapseFilters').removeClass('show');
        } else {
            $('.collapse#collapseFilters').addClass('show');
        };
    });
    
    // Range slider
    $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({
        polyfill: false,
        onInit: function () {
            this.output = $(".distance span").html(this.$element.val());
        },
        onSlide: function (
            position, value) {
            this.output.html(value);
        }
    });
    
    //Footer collapse
    var $headingFooter = $('footer h3');
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width() <= 575) {
            $headingFooter.attr("data-toggle","collapse");
        } else {
          $headingFooter.removeAttr("data-toggle","collapse");
        }
    }).resize();
    $headingFooter.on("click", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('opened');
    });
    
    // Carousels
    $('#carousel').owlCarousel({
        center: true,
        items: 2,
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                dots:false
            },
            600: {
                items: 2
            },
            1000: {
                items: 4
            }
        }
    });
    $('#reccomended').owlCarousel({
        center: true,
        items: 2,
        loop: true,
        margin: 0,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 2
            },
            767: {
                items: 2
            },
            1000: {
                items: 3
            },
            1400: {
                items: 4
            }
        }
    });
    
    // Sticky filters
    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width <= 991) {
            $('.sticky_horizontal').stick_in_parent({
                offset_top: 40
            });
        } else {
            $('.sticky_horizontal').stick_in_parent({
                offset_top: 60          
            });
        }
    }); 
    
    // Sticky horizontal results list page or detail page
    $("#results,.sticky_horizontal_2").stick_in_parent({
        offset_top: 0
    });
    
    // Sticky results map view
    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width <= 991) {
            $('#results_map_view').stick_in_parent({
                offset_top: 47
            });
        } else {
            $('#results_map_view').stick_in_parent({
                offset_top: 58          
            });
        }
    });
                
    // Secondary nav scroll
    var $sticky_nav= $('.secondary_nav');
    $sticky_nav.find('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 85
        }, 800, 'swing');
    });
    $sticky_nav.find('ul li a').on('click', function () {
        $sticky_nav.find('ul li a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    
    $('#faq_box a[href^="#"]').on('click', function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
            || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
               if (target.length) {
                 $('html,body').animate({
                     scrollTop: target.offset().top -195
                }, 800);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    $('ul#cat_nav li a').on('click', function () {
        $('ul#cat_nav li a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    
    // Button show/hide map
    $(".btn_map, .btn_map_in, .btn_filt").on("click", function () {
        var el = $(this);
        el.text() == el.data("text-swap") ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("body").offset().top
        }, 600);
    });
    
    // Button map view
    $(".btn_map_view").on("click", function () {
        var el = $(this);
        el.text() == el.data("text-swap") ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
    });
    
    
})(window.jQuery);
```

Please Help, Thanks in advance

I've tried some solutions but didn't resolve

Comment: I strongly suggest using React-Bootstrap and getting rid of as much of that jQuery as you can. You shouldn't be manipulating the DOM directly in a React app. You're also tangling another menu library and something with canvas in here. I'd try to simplify first.